# Host name resolution without a DNS server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, azure

I have a virtual network setup in the Azure cloud.  The virtual machines (all with Windows Server 2008) can only identify each other by IP and not by host name.  [To do this I need to set up my own DNS server in the virtual network.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854481/networking-between-virtual-machines-in-a-virtual-network)  I do not have the expertise to do this.

Is there not a way to locally configure DNS 'bindings' in each virtual machines' TCP/IP settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to add entries in each server's hosts file, located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Run Notepad as administrator, then open this file and add lines like this, one line per server:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx myserver
```

I would advise that you invest in the time to deploy DNS in your environment. Managing hosts files does not scale whatosever past a small handful of machines.

Comment: This is perfect for now, thanks.  Yes, I would like to implement DNS, but I've done some reading and it's mostly going over my head.  Could you perhaps provide me with a starting point?  Software to use?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 has a DNS server role. It's quite simple to install and the wizards will get you started with a basic installation. You'd then specify that DNS server as the first DNS server in each machine's IP configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  Another question: How would those machines then resolve Internet domains if they are only pointing to an internal DNS?

Comment: @davenewza In the DNS server you set up a "forwarder," which is exactly what it sounds like. DNS requests that the DNS server can't answer (aka for domains you don't host) get sent along to the forwarder, which is generally a well-known DNS service like Google's public DNS.

Comment: You would point the 2008 server at an other DNS server. It is like asking your secretary to answer all local queries. When she does not know she 'phones out'.